# In which episode does Merlin reveal his power to King Arthur?

Tags: episode-identification, merlin-bbc

I was concerned if this will take part in one of the very last parts of the series.

**In which episode does Merlin finally reveal the extent of his powers to King Arthur?**

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's **the very last episode**, season 5 episode 13:

(I searched Google for `BBC Merlin reveal powers` and this video was the second hit.)